# in function how to stop visual mode and how to run a mapping

Tags: visual-mode

Assume I am inside a function and currently in visual mode (`mode()` returns `v` or `V` or `"\<c-v>"`, such as when you run `vmap-expr`)

How can I quit the visual mode? Should I call `feedkeys("\<esc>", 'ni')`?

How to run a mapping in the visual mode, like `4>` to indent the lines 4 times. It seems `normal 4>` does not work.

Comment: `>` already works in visual mode, what you need the mapping for?

Comment: I need to do a lot of other things after indentation. The question is actually general: how to type some keystroke or execute a visual mapping <Plug>xxx in function in visual mode.

Comment: so have you tried using `xmap`?

Comment: I have some vmaps that calls functions. I use something like `vmap ,x :<C-U>call MyFunc()<CR>`. Inside the function I could do `normal gv4>`. See `help gv`. How do you call your function?

Comment: @Ralf : makes you in normal mode. I use vmap <express> Func() so that I am still in visual mode(). Or it is because I did “normal gv “.

Comment: While executing the function `visualmode()` returns `v,` `V` or `\<C-V>`. The marks `\`<` and `\`>` are set and I can revive the visual mode with gv. `<C-U>` just removes the leading `'<,'>` from the command line.

Comment: `visualmode()` returns the last used visual mode not the current mode. `mode()` returns the current mode. Because you already exited visual mode by using `:`, so that way works for you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of another comment:

As far as I understand you want to work with `vmap <expr>` Like mapping `,"` to a function:

```
vmap <expr> ," MyFunction()
```

In this case the the function has to return the keystrokes that should be executed by Vim. Lets assume you want to surround visually selected text with something (function hardly tested):

```
function! ExecSurround(pre, post)
    let mode = mode()
    if(mode == "V")
        " line: Put it above and below the selected lines
        return "V`>o" . a:post . "\e`<O" . a:pre . "\e"
    elseif(mode == "\<C-V>")
        " block: Put it before and after selection on every line
        return "A" . a:post . "\egvI" . a:pre . "\e"
    else
        " char: put it before first and after last char
        return "v`>a" . a:post . "\e`<i" . a:pre . "\e"
    endif
endfunction

vmap <expr> ," ExecSurround('"', '"')
```

As far as I understand `:help :map-expression`, the things you can do in the function are limited. You have to return the keystrokes, that change your text.

As said in my comment, I would choose another way:

```
function! Surround(pre, post)
    let mode = visualmode()
    if(mode == "V")
        call execute("normal `>o" . a:post . "\e`<O" . a:pre . "\e")
    elseif(mode == "\<C-V>")
        call execute("normal gvA" . a:post . "\egvI" . a:pre . "\e")
    else
        call execute("normal `>a" . a:post . "\e`<i" . a:pre . "\e")
    endif   
endfunction

vmap ," :<C-U>call Surround('"', '"')<CR>
```

That way you are not limited by the restrictions from "map-expression" and could easily add additional functionality.

Whatever you want to do might be more complex than this, but perhaps it helps to go on.